# PostgreSQL transform json to composite type

Tags: json, postgresql-9.4

i'm experimenting with the new json functions in POstgreSQL 9.4 and find most of them very usefull. For example transforming a Composite type into json in order to help back end processes to map a functions result easier.

but what i can't get working is the other way, transforming a json string into an object of a Composite type.

please note that the functioncall to_json(...) is used here to simulate a json string that has the exact structure of the composite type

```
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS myType_1;
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS myType_0;

CREATE TYPE myType_0 AS (
    id SMALLINT,
    name TEXT
);

CREATE TYPE myType_1 AS (
    since TIMESTAMP,
    objects myType_0[]
);


SELECT json_populate_record(NULL::myType_1, 
                            to_json( ROW( now(), 
                                          ARRAY[ROW(1,'name1')::myType_0, 
                                                ROW(2,'name2')::myType_0, 
                                                ROW(4,'name3')::myType_0])::myType_1))
```

the code Returns

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "[{"id":1,"name":"name1"},{"id":2,"name":"name2"},{"id":4,"name":"name3"}]"
DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
```